# Rails: Is it better to make multiple find calls OR pass a user object to multiple methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it better to go pass a simple ID and make multiple ActiveRecord find queries:

```
def some_method(user_id)
  @user = User.find(user_id)
  SomeClass.call_method(user_id)
end

class SomeClass
  def call_method(user_id)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
  end
end
```

OR pass an actual ActiveRecord object through to different methods?

```
def some_method(user_id)
  @user = User.find(user_id)
  SomeClass.call_method(@user)
end

class SomeClass
  def call_method(user)
    @user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The second option seems like the better option as you are only making one database call.
In the first version, the second database call might be cached and so might be quick, but it seems unnecessary.

Also from a design point of view I think it is better practise to give the method a User object rather than an id. By giving the method an object it doesn't have to know anything about how to retrieve the User object. So if you changed your application so that the user came from a different data source (a web service for example) then this method wouldn't be effected.